# Can we make a polygon with one point ? in R

Tags: r, polygon, raster, spatial, r-sf

I have points in longitude latitude I will want to make a square so that my point is the center of the square to display it on a leaflet map later.
So can I make a polygon where my point it's the center ? in R
If yes, how ?

Comment: A combination of `st_buffer` and `st_bbox` should work

Comment: How has this received 3 up votes?